# Exclude one specific file from regex (webpack plugin)

Tags: regex, webpack, plugins, regex-lookarounds

I am struggling with the following issue. I have a webpack plugin that is optimizing my css files. Now I want to exclude one specific file from being processed.

This is the plugin:
https://github.com/NMFR/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin
Now there is an option to specify the file pattern that should be processed:
`assetNameRegExp: /\.optimize\.css$/g,`

**Now I want to exclude one speficic file: `my-stylesheet.css`**

I tried a lot of things and I am pretty sure that I will need some negative lookaheads, but I can't get it to work.

So far I am here:
`/^.*(?!my-stylesheet\.css)/` or event without the preceding characters:
`/^(?!my-stylesheet\.css)$/`

But it will always match.
What am I doing wrong?

- whatever.scss `should match` (I don't know if at that point I still have scss files)
- another/css.css `should match`
- my-other-stylesheet.css `should match`
- my-stylesheet.css `should NOT match`

Thank you so much in advance for your help.
Cheers

Comment: `/^(?!my-stylesheet\.css)$/` only matches an empty string, it is equal to  `^$`, you need `/^(?!my-stylesheet\.css$)/` or `/^(?!my-stylesheet\.css$).*/`. Or, if it should not end with the string: `/^(?!.*my-stylesheet\.css$)/` / `/^(?!.*my-stylesheet\.css$).*/`

Comment: Of course one finds the solution right after asking the question:
this did the trick for me:
https://regex101.com/r/OjtVIH/2
`/^(?!.*my-stylesheet.css).*$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your solution seems to work as well. Thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: Do not forget to escape the literal dot in the regex patterns.

Comment: Yeah true, I did that, but in my comment I forgot. Thank you.